# python multiprocessing очередь

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Имеется около 1800 папок, в каждой txt-файлы от 1 до 2500 шт. Нужно все обработать. Я разделил все папки на диапазоны, 0..180, 181-360 и т.д. Диапазоны передал в 10 потоков. Все работает. Вопрос мой в следующем: как создать очередь потоков, к примеру также 10, но передавать туда не диапазон, а одну папку, и, чтобы отработав, поток брал следующую? Как при этом избежать блокировки, что бы одновременно освободившиеся потоки не взяли одно и то же задание?

пример моего кода

```
def writer(start, stop, num):
    v_id_count = 0
    v_Count = 0
    out = open('C:\\chunks\\part_'+str(num)+'.txt', 'w')
    for i in islice(dirs,start,stop):
        id = i
        v_id_count += 1
        p = '{}\\{}'.format(path,i)
        files = [z for z in os.listdir(p)]
        for file in files:
            file_path = '{}\\{}'.format(p, file)
            f = open(file_path, 'r').read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
            # cur = con.cursor()
            v_Count_loop = 0
            try:
                for v in range(get_count(soup)):
                    string = '{};{};{};{};{};{};{}'.format(id, get_status_date(soup), get_status(soup), get_z_name(soup),get_d_name(soup),
                                                           get_method(soup, v), get_description(soup, v))
                    out.write(string + '\n')
                    v_Count += 1
                    v_Count_loop += 1
                    print('Поток {}. Вставлено {} строк. Всего вставлено {}. Обработано id {}'.format(num, v_Count_loop, v_Count, v_inn_count))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    out.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path = 'C:\\html'
    dirs = [x for x in os.listdir(path)]

    maxpoint = len(dirs)

    params = []

    #делим на диапазоны
    for i in range(1,11):
        if round(maxpoint/10 * (i-1)) == 0:
            st = round(maxpoint/10 * (i-1))
        else:
            st = round(maxpoint/10 * (i-1)) + 1
        ed = round(maxpoint/10*i)
        args = st, ed, i
        params.append(args)

    # print(params[0])

    p1 = Process(target = writer, args=params[0])
    p2 = Process(target = writer, args=params[1])
    p3 = Process(target = writer, args=params[2])
    p4 = Process(target = writer, args=params[3])
    p5 = Process(target = writer, args=params[4])
    p6 = Process(target = writer, args=params[5])
    p7 = Process(target = writer, args=params[6])
    p8 = Process(target = writer, args=params[7])
    p9 = Process(target = writer, args=params[8])
    p10 = Process(target = writer, args=params[9])

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()
    p6.start()
    p7.start()
    p8.start()
    p9.start()
    p10.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
    p6.join()
    p7.join()
    p8.join()
    p9.join()
    p10.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

работа - в пуле процессов

запись/чтение файлов - в главном

```
from os import path, walk
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

def files_from_dir(dir_: str) -> iter:
    '''генератор файлов'''
    for root, dirs, files in walk(dir_):
        for file in files:
            yield path.join(root, file)

def file_worker(name: str) -> tuple:
    '''обработка файла(в потоке)'''
    with file_lock:
        return name, str(len(open(name).read()))

def set_pool_lock(lock: Lock) -> None:
    global file_lock
    file_lock = lock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_lock = Lock()  # лок на чтение/запись файлов на диск
    with Pool(processes=10, initializer=set_pool_lock, initargs=[file_lock]) as pool:
        # обработка файлов из file_worker в пуле-процессов pool
        for name, text_len in pool.imap_unordered(file_worker, files_from_dir('TEMP')):
            with file_lock:  # логирование результата работы file_worker
                with open('%s.log' % name, 'w') as log:
                    log.write(text_len)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Предыдущий Ваш пример был понятнее( А как здесь реализованы блокировки? или их не будет?

Comment: Тк смысла паралелить работу с диском нет, работа(i/o) с файлами происходит последовательно, в отдельном процессе. Передача заданий в  worker-процесс происходит средствами multiprocessing .Pool, который сам обо всем заботится. Те блокировки не нужны.